# How to change the placeholder in the textbox by changing checkbox using angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the placeholder in the textbox by changing the checkbox using angular. I tried fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d9uc1dxc/5/.

I have the following code:

```
 **SCRIPT**
  function TController($scope) {
$scope.placeholder="%";

$scope.formData = {};

$scope.radioChecked = function ()
{
    $scope.placeholder="%";
    $scope.apply();
}

$scope.radiounChecked = function ()
{
    $scope.placeholder="Count";
    $scope.apply();
}
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is (1) if I change to "%" then the textbox placeholder and (2) if I change to "Count" then the textbox placeholder should change to "Count".
Someone please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to use this code

this is the script file

```
    var app = angular.module("TestApp", []);

function TController($scope) {
    $scope.placeholder="%";

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.radioChecked = function ()
    {
        if($scope.placeholder == "%"){
            $scope.placeholder = "Count";
        }else{
            $scope.placeholder = "%";
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the html file

```
<body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TController">
            <div class="flw vreq2">
                <label>Voting require2</label>
                <div class="oneline">
                   <div class="onoffswitches">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" ng-click="radioChecked()" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch7"/>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch7">
                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                             </label>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="per1">
                <input  type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="formData.textInput" />
            </div>
</body>
```

hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the two functions for `checked` & `unchecked`

use `ng-change` in check box as and add a model to checkbox // model name = onoffswitch

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="onoffswitch" ng-change="radioChecked()" ...
```

when checkbox `checked`, `onoffswitch` model value will be `true` otherwise `false`

when changing the checkbox `radioChecked()` function will invoke

```
$scope.radioChecked = function ()
{
  if($scope.onoffswitch) {
    $scope.placeholder="%";
  } else {
    $scope.placeholder="Count";
  }
}
```

see the [demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvd70da1Gsuv51I6wjxq?p=preview)